# What is pure JAX-RS way to get request's IP?

Tags: servlets, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

It is possible to get client ip address by adding servlet api in classpath and adding following in resource class.

```
public String getData(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
   String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Is there any way in pure JAX RS app to get remote host IP ? Without needing servelt-api. Something like,

```
public String getData(@Context javax.ws.rs.core.Request request){
   String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in JAX-RS. What's wrong with HttpServletRequest? Are you not using a servlet container?

Comment: I am using Jersey 2.25, there is no servlet-api in pom.xml. Not even in resolved dependencies. To make my application fully JAX RS I wish not to use servlet api. Instead rely on JAX RS ways. You mean is it impossible ?

Comment: In the specification, JAX-RS is defined to work in a servlet container. All implementations support the injection of the HttpServletRequest. So you will still be portable using the HttpServletRequest

Comment: Do you mean JAX RS is on the top of the servlet-api? If so then, it should have been previously referenced by JAX RS. But I had to add it manually in pom.xml. Why ?

Comment: Jersey uses the servlet api dependency, but its [scope is provided](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b07/containers/jersey-servlet-core/pom.xml#L63), so it won't show up in your dependencies. I don't know why they do it like this. Probably because its already provided by the servlet container.

Comment: Now I feel... I should delete this question... Thank you very very much. :) :)